# Converting between rates using a common base rate

Tags: algorithms

If I have a base rate of USD = 1 and know that all conversion rates are in relation to that currency, how would I convert other currencies between each other using that commonality?

For instance, I know 1 USD = 0.594246 GBP and 1 USD = 0.744712 EUR.

Using that, how would I convert GBP into EUR?

For instance, 10 GBP is how many EUR? Or 10 EUR is how many GBP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember doing this in chemistry, it was called dimensional analysis. Basically you turn a relationship such as $1\: USD = 0.594246\: GBP$ into $\frac{1\: USD}{0.594246\: GBP}=1$
. $1$ doesn't affect multiplication, but you can "cancel" units this way. For example, to convert 10 GBP into EUR,

$10\:GBP=(10\: GBP)\cdot (\frac{1 \: USD}{0.594246 \: GBP})\cdot(\frac{0.744712  \: EUR}{1 \: USD})=12.532049\: EUR$

Notice that the $GBP$s and $USD$s cancel, and we are left with $EUR$s. But since those fractions are equal to $1$, the value hasn't changed, but the units have! Quite nice huh?

Comment: Beautiful! I took chemistry way back, and we used this, but I could not for the life of me remember that it was called dimensional analysis. Such a handy technique.

Comment: I remember one problem in chemistry we had: An employee works flipping hamburgers. She makes $8.00 an hour, works 8 hours a day, 5 days a week, 50 weeks a year. How many years will she be flipping burgers before she's a millionare ?!

Comment: That sounds more like masochistic trip into philosophy meant to convince you to finish your degree.